$I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \arcsin(1-x^n) \,dx $
Find the limit of the sequence $(I_n) _n$ wherw $I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \arcsin(1-x^n) \,dx $.
I try to integrate by parts but I get $\infty \cdot 0$.
I need to practice more examples. Can you recommend some books with exercises?

what theorems are you allowed to use?

If you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, you need to justify moving it inside the integral.

@SineoftheTime I am a highschool student.

you did not answer my question

First of all you know that the limit exists since the sequenze is monotone.
Note that $\arcsin(1-x^n) ≤\pi/2$, so the limit is $≤\pi/2$.
Now we need a lower bound: note that in each interval of the form [0,1-1/n] the functions $\arcsin(1-x^n)$ converge uniformly due to Dini's lemma, so we can swap limit and integral  and we obtain that the integral is $≥l\times\pi/2$ where $l$ is the lenght of the intervall. Thus the limit is $\pi/2$

Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our quality standard policy. Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.
